# Why isn't the number subtracted in PlayerPrefs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone In my code, when you click on the button, a number should be subtracted and saved in PlayerPrefs , the number is subtracted, but does not save . I also learned that the number is saved when you exit the game because of the OnApplicationQuit method, how to make the number normally saved?

```
    public class Chest_Money : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int NumCharector;
    public int money;
    public int Rand;

    public Text text;

    public GameObject NotMoney;
    public GameObject[] Charectors;
    public GameObject Panel;
    public GameObject Panel2;

    public bool bla2;

    
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money_S", 0);
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        
        
    }
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause){
            if(pause){
                //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money_S" , money);
                
            }
        }
#endif
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money_S" , money);
        
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money_S", money);
        text.text = "$:" + money;
        
        if(bla2 == true){
            Panel2.SetActive(true);
            
        }
    }
    public void Chest(){
        if(money >= 100){
            money -= 100;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money_S", money);
            
            
            StartCoroutine(Wait2());
        }
        else {
            NotMoney.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(Wait4());
        }
        
    }
    
   
    IEnumerator Wait4(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        NotMoney.SetActive(false);
    }
    IEnumerator Wait2()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scins");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can/should use [`PlayerPrefs.Save`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) to force a save on certain checkpoints

> By default Unity writes preferences to disk during `OnApplicationQuit()`. In cases when the game crashes or otherwise prematuraly exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game. This function will write to disk potentially causing a small hiccup, therefore it is not recommended to call during actual gameplay.

I then also suggest you rather use a property like

```
private int _money;

public int money
{
    get => _money;
    set
    {
        _money = value;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money_S");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        text.text = "$:" + money;
    }
}
```

So it only updates the text and saves the value once it actually changes.

This way you don't need to update the text or set the value **every frame** in `Update`.